# Conditionally change the nillable property of a simple type

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, conditional-statements

I'm trying to conditionally change an element from being nillable to non-nillable based on the value of 2 other elements in an XSD . Is this possible in XSD 1.1?

I have 3 simple types of type xs:int : VenGrp, VenTyp, SubVen.

VenGrp and VenTyp are non-nillable
SubVen is non-nillable if VenGrp=2 and VenTyp=2 and nillable otherwise.

Is it possible to do this in an XSD schema file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. It would be possible if VenGrp and VenTyp were attributes: you could then use conditional type assignment.

Are you really sure you want to be using xsi:nil anyway? I thought the general consensus was that it was a bad feature best forgotten.

Comment: The problem is that the 3 values need to exist in the XML file at all times, even when they don't have a value. Is there another way of making sure they have a value without using the xs:nil?

Comment: If there is no value for element X, you can represent this in three ways: (a) omit element X, (b) have X present but empty (`<X/>`), (c)  use `<X xsi:nil="true"/>`. My first preference would be (a), my second preference would be (b), and I find it very hard to understand why anyone would want to do (c).